# CDATA removed in target xml

Tags: xslt-1.0, cdata

I'm trying to Copy an XML as it is using XSLT. My input XML contains CDATA section. The Output Strips the CDATA and keeps its contents. I want to just make an exact copy of input XML(Including CDATA tags). kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the CDATA doesn't contain any characters that have a special meaning, stripping the CDATA while keeping the content intact does not change anything as far as XML semantics is concerned. So from the view of an XML processor, you *are* creating an exact copy. If you want to keep the bytes intact, don't use an XML parser.

Comment: My input XML Belongs to a particular Schema. The CDATA contains Another XML in it. So my output might not be a correct one when validated. Is there any way that i can just send the input through as it is. Or may be any java code that i can use in my xsl ? I have to be doing it in xsl. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `cdata-section-elements` attribute on `<xsl:output>` element. That attribute takes a whitespace separated list of element names (QNames) whose text node children should be output using CDATA sections.

For more info see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output